# How to insert bulk JSON data with node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, promise, es6-promise

What i trying to achieve here is i want to insert this JSON into my database, which is my database is using sql server. I have bulk json data, that contain details as the json tree. below is the JSON data, i want to insert

```
[
   {
      No_BPS:'BSWEB12345',
      Kd_Plg:'MMIM026',
      Nm_Plg:'YAOMING',
      Tgl_BPS:'2017-02-27T08:39:38.971Z',
      Entry_Time:'2017-02-27T08:39:38.971Z',
      User_Name:'tes',
      Status:'Y',
      Kd_Teknisi:'tes',
      No_Ref:'RIRIMIMI609-001',
      detailsData:[
         {
            No_BPS:'BSWEB12345',
            Kd_Brg:'RH-C779-SB',
            Qty:2,
            Alasan:'undefined',
            Keterangan:'undefined'
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      No_BPS:'BSWEB99999',
      Kd_Plg:'PTPS053',
      Nm_Plg:'WARLORD',
      Tgl_BPS:'2017-02-27T08:40:04.082Z',
      Entry_Time:'2017-02-27T08:40:04.082Z',
      User_Name:'tes',
      Status:'Y',
      Kd_Teknisi:'tes',
      No_Ref:'PTKP1210-001',
      detailsData:[
         {
            No_BPS:'BSWEB99999',
            Kd_Brg:'PS-230BIT SNI',
            Qty:1,
            Alasan:'undefined',
            Keterangan:'undefined'
         },
         {
            No_BPS:'BSWEB99999',
            Kd_Brg:'PS-130BIT SNI',
            Qty:1,
            Alasan:'undefined',
            Keterangan:'undefined'
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

and here is my nodejs code :

```
exports.insert_BPS = function(req, resp) {
    console.log(req.body);
    req.body.map(headerdata=>
        {
            var sql = `INSERT INTO TblBPSHeader (
                        No_BPS, Kd_Plg, Tgl_BPS, Entry_Time, User_Name, Status, Kd_Teknisi) values
                        ('` + headerdata.No_BPS + `', 
                        '` + headerdata.Kd_Plg + `',
                        '` + dateFormat(headerdata.Tgl_BPS, "yyyy-mm-dd' 'HH:MM:ss") + `',
                        '` + dateFormat(headerdata.Entry_Time, "yyyy-mm-dd' 'HH:MM:ss") + `',
                        '` + headerdata.User_Name + `',
                        '` + headerdata.Status + `', 
                        '` + headerdata.Kd_Teknisi + `')`

            db.executeSql(sql, function(data, err) {
                if (err) {
                    httpMsgs.show500(req, resp, err);
                } else {
                    // httpMsgs.send200(req, resp);
                    console.log('header inserted');
                };
            });
            Promise.all(headerdata.detailsData.map
                (detaildata => 

                    {
                        console.log(detaildata);
                        var sqldetail = `INSERT INTO TblBPSDetail (
                                    No_BPS, kd_Brg, Qty, Alasan, Keterangan) values
                                    ('` + detaildata.No_BPS + `', 
                                    '` + detaildata.Kd_Brg + `',
                                    '` + detaildata.Qty + `',
                                    '` + detaildata.Alasan + `',
                                    '` + detaildata.Keterangan + `')`

                        db.executeSql(sqldetail, function(data, err) {
                            if (err) {
                                httpMsgs.show500(req, resp, err);
                            } else {
                                // httpMsgs.send200(req, resp);
                                console.log('detail inserted');
                            };
                        });
                    }
                )
            )
        }
    )
};
```

but turn out the data is inserted but it's duplicating, it always loop the data when, after first insert the data it's a success inserted all the data, but when i leave it for a moment, it do inserting once more it self so the data will duplicated and cause duplicate error. How do i insert a bulk data json properly?

Comment: interesting random use of `Promise.all` on a map that returns undefined -

Comment: Side note: we are in 2017, don't inject raw values into SQL as a caveman, use prepared statements. It'll also prevent you script from crashing randomly when data happens to contain single quotes and other special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you want Promises to get this code working, although your code doesn't seem to actually use Promises at all - despite the random `Promise.all` buried in there!

Firstly, to use Promises, you'll want a "promisified" `exectueSql` - once you've got that, the rest is actually quite straight forward

```
exports.insert_BPS = function(req, resp) {
    // a promisified executeSql
    let executeSql = (db, sql) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => db.executeSql(sql, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return reject(err);
        }
        resolve(data);
    }));

    return Promise.all(req.body.map(headerdata => {
        var sql = `INSERT INTO TblBPSHeader (
                    No_BPS, Kd_Plg, Tgl_BPS, Entry_Time, User_Name, Status, Kd_Teknisi) values
                    ('` + headerdata.No_BPS + `', 
                    '` + headerdata.Kd_Plg + `',
                    '` + dateFormat(headerdata.Tgl_BPS, "yyyy-mm-dd' 'HH:MM:ss") + `',
                    '` + dateFormat(headerdata.Entry_Time, "yyyy-mm-dd' 'HH:MM:ss") + `',
                    '` + headerdata.User_Name + `',
                    '` + headerdata.Status + `', 
                    '` + headerdata.Kd_Teknisi + `')`
        return executeSql(db, sql)
        .then(() => Promise.all(headerdata.detailsData.map(detaildata => {
            var sqldetail = `INSERT INTO TblBPSDetail (
                                No_BPS, kd_Brg, Qty, Alasan, Keterangan) values
                                ('` + detaildata.No_BPS + `', 
                                '` + detaildata.Kd_Brg + `',
                                '` + detaildata.Qty + `',
                                '` + detaildata.Alasan + `',
                                '` + detaildata.Keterangan + `')`
            return executeSql(db, sqldetail);            
        })));
    })).then(results => {
        // all done here
        httpMsgs.send200(req, resp);
    }).catch(reason => {
        httpMsgs.show500(req, resp, reason);
    });
};
```